# What is the default value of physicsClientId?

Tags: pybullet

More or less all functions of pyBullet take an optional argument `physicsClientId` which is needed when multiple instances are running in parallel.

When writing custom functions that call pybullet internally, I would like to provide this as an optional argument there as well.  So I tried the following:

```py
def my_func(..., physicsClientId=None):
    pybullet.some_func(
        ...,
        physicsClientId=physicsClientId,
    )
```

However, when I call this without specifying the ID, I get

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)

so `None` is obviously the wrong default value.  As it want's an integer, I assume it is something like `0` or `-1` but I would like to know if there is an official answer to this (in the pyBullet documentation, there are typically no default values specified for optional arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the code ([pybullet.c](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/pybullet.c)), it seems the default is `0`.

And indeed, `def my_func(..., physicsClientId=0)` is working.